# Can't bind tableview cell's "Selected" property

Tags: mvvmcross

I have a view model

```
public class ComplectationSubItemWrapper: MvxViewModel
{
    public ComplectationSubItemWrapper ()
    {
    }

    private ComplectationSubItem _complectationSubItem;
    public ComplectationSubItem ComplectationSubItem
    { 
        get { return _complectationSubItem; }
        set { _complectationSubItem = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => ComplectationSubItem); }
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get{ return _isSelected; }
        set {
            _isSelected = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsSelected);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I bind IsSelected property to TableCell's Selected?
I tried:

```
this.DelayBind(() => {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<GenericPopoverCell, ComplectationSubItemWrapper>();
            set.Bind(lblTitle).To(vm => vm.ComplectationSubItem.Title);
            set.Bind(this).For(s => s.Selected).To(vm => vm.IsSelected);
            set.Apply ();
        });
```

but this is not working. It seems that Selected property is initialized before binding occures. SelectionChangedCommand is not suitable because I need AllowsMultipleSelection.

Comment: What does `It seems that Selected property is initialized before binding occurs.` mean? You can always add a custom binding for this if the default property binding isn't sufficient - but I'm not currently sure what the problem you are seeing is.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to properly bind UITableView with multiselection, especially how to handle deselection, and how to initialize tablecells to be selected when table view is loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Stuart, it seems that I found the solution to my problem: `public override void ItemDeselected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
  {
   var item = GetItemAt(indexPath);

   var command = SelectionChangedCommand;
   if (command != null)
    command.Execute(item);
  }`